# Running a python script that opens a window with crontab

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi2

I'm a newbie to python, and crontab, so I don't know exactly how to do the task.
This is my friend's program. It's a countdown clock, starting at 5 minutes and counting down to zero. I took out many of the notes to slim it down.

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
import time
def count_down():
    for t in range(298, -1, -1):
        sf = "{t:01d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod(t,60))
        #print(sf) # test
        time_str.set(sf)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
root = tk.Tk()
time_str = tk.StringVar()
label_font = ('helvetica'), 535)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=time_str, font=label_font, bg='mediumblue', 
    fg='white', relief='raised', bd=3).pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)
for t in range (297, -1, -1):
    sf = "{01d:}{:02d}".format(*divmod(t, 60))
    time_str.set(sf)
    root.update()
    time.sleep(.958)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, the problem lies in crontab. I have created a crontab, which is

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Desktop/clock/5minute.py
```

The 5 asterisks are for testing purposes. It should run at specific times later on. The program itself is already set with 777 permissions. I've tried running the crontab using parameters like `export DISPLAY=:0 &&` but nothing's worked. I'm still learning, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling the above with python /home/pi/Desktop/clock/5minute.py  in the crontab?

Comment: Whichever problem you are trying to solve, **`chmod 777` is wrong and dangerous** -- you should revert to sane permissions (notably, disable world write permissions) before you do anything else.

Comment: `cron` does not have access to your X session.  Even if there is a single X session on `DISPLAY=:0` there is no simple way for your `cron` daemon to interact with it; nor should there be.  You should run something from within your own `.xsession` or similar instead.  This is a FAQ.

Comment: @toasteez the directory refers to the mentioned script

Comment: @tripleee I've fixed the permissions. Could you direct me to more information on X sessions? Thank you.

Comment: Quick googling gets me e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3

Answer (score -2):

Change your crontab settings from current to this it'll work.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/clock/5minute.py
```

Over here you're not mentioning python path that may be the reason you've facing difficulty making it work.

Comment: Have you set time. try */2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/clock/5minute.py    This will start after 2 mins

Comment: By set time, do you mean I should set the time to my timezone again? I'll try it soon. Thank you.

Comment: I'm asking you to test this code by just setting your cron task after 2 mins.

Comment: you can monitor whether your cron task is working or not by going to /var/log/syslog

Comment: After checking the syslog, it runs the command. The output goes to Dec 7 11:09:01 /USR/SBIN/CRON[2305]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/clock/5mintute.py                After that line, the (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output). I think it just doesn't take the output and use it, but since there isn't something installed, it won't work.

Comment: I think @tripleee is correct above cron does not have access to your X session

Comment: Did it solution from @tripleee solved your prob. P.S for further information where you are going wrong you can check auth.log and error log in same path with matching time stamp.